# Validate certificates NodeJS

Tags: node.js, openssl, certificate, ca

Is there any way to validate certificates against a CA, similar to the command "openssl verify -CAfile"?

I need to do this to bypass the HTTPS check Node JS with rejectUnauthorized: true, because with selfsigned certificates already realized that it is virtually impossible to authenticate the client with SSL.

Comment: Do you have a self signed certificate (2nd paragraph), or do you have your own CA (1st paragraph)? Many user agents have moved against self signed certificates, so you will find the easiest path over time is to run your own CA, and install it on your devices.